# iPhone Clear Caches Easily

Tags: iphone, caching

while developing websites I contantly need to empty my caches to see the changes take place, on my Mac it's one click, however on the iPhone I need to dig down menus all the way to Clear Website Data. There must be a quicker way I don't know of. I know you can create a shortcut to clear caches and all history but I don't want to clear history. Is there any other way? Thanks.